# Can I combine the output from two vectors using a for-loop, so that the nth element is paired with the nth element?

Tags: r

I'm trying to automate some tedious code-writing. I have something like the following:

```
Codes<-c("code1","code2","code3","code4")
other_Codes<-c("code5","code6","code7","code8")
```

What I want to create is something like the following:

```
repetetivetext Code1 repetetivetext Code5 
repetetivetext Code2 repetetivetext Code6 
repetetivetext Code3 repetetivetext Code7
repetetivetext Code4 repetetivetext Code8
```

....So that the first argument in the first vector is paired with the first argument in the second vector and so on. This can be done with something like:

```
paste0("repetetivetext ",Codes, "repetitive text ", other_Codes)
```

But for different reason (the actual code is more complex than this) this isn't a workable solution right now. I would much rather use a variation of a for loop or nested for-loop, one which would let me combine the elements from the two vectors, but give me 4 combinations instead of 16.

Is there such a variation? Or is there a different way of doing this which I haven't thought of?

Comment: your question is ambiguous. what do you want? post expected output

Comment: Yes you can use a for loop, but without understanding why it's not clear why it's required or better than the simple vectorised solution you've shown here.  Specifically, what is required when you write "one which would let me combine the elements from the two vectors, but give me 4 combinations instead of 16." - do you mean by using different orders?

Comment: If you don't like `paste0` you can use `sprintf("repetetivetext %s repetetivetext %s", Codes, other_Codes)`. Writing a `for` loop to create this character vector is trivial but dumb.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I specified that the first argument in the first vector should be paired with the first argument in the second vector and so fort. I illustrated this point in my expected output and just to be sure I specified it once more in the title of the question,

Comment: @Magnus but `paste0("repetetivetext ",Codes, "repetitive text ", other_Codes)` does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use just 1 iteration of 'for loop', perhaps you look for something like this? :

```
Codes <- c("code1", "code2", "code3", "code4")
other_Codes <- c("code5", "code6", "code7", "code8")
output = c()
text = "repetetivetext "
for (j in 1:length(Codes)) { 
    element = paste0(text, Codes[j], text,other_Codes[j])
    output  = c(output, element)
}
output
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the two vectors both of which consist of four elements to get all 16 combinations,
you have to multiply the elements of a vector according to the length of the other vector. You can do that in a (nested) for-loop using `purrr::map2` and its family (e.g. `purrr::map2_chr`).

```
library(purrr)

Codes <- c("code1", "code2", "code3", "code4")
other_Codes <- c("code5", "code6", "code7", "code8")

map2_chr(
  .x = rep(Codes, each = length(other_Codes)),
  .y = rep(other_Codes, times = length(Codes)),
  ~ paste0("repetetive text ", .x, " repetitive text ", .y)
)

#  [1] "repetetive text code1 repetitive text code5"
#  [2] "repetetive text code1 repetitive text code6"
#  [3] "repetetive text code1 repetitive text code7"
#  [4] "repetetive text code1 repetitive text code8"
#  [5] "repetetive text code2 repetitive text code5"
#  [6] "repetetive text code2 repetitive text code6"
#  [7] "repetetive text code2 repetitive text code7"
#  [8] "repetetive text code2 repetitive text code8"
#  [9] "repetetive text code3 repetitive text code5"
# [10] "repetetive text code3 repetitive text code6"
# [11] "repetetive text code3 repetitive text code7"
# [12] "repetetive text code3 repetitive text code8"
# [13] "repetetive text code4 repetitive text code5"
# [14] "repetetive text code4 repetitive text code6"
# [15] "repetetive text code4 repetitive text code7"
# [16] "repetetive text code4 repetitive text code8"
```

Comment: All 16 permutations would seem to be exactly NOT required, though I admit the question is oddly posed.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I know that the permutations are probably not necessary and that the original question is not clear, but I leave this answer for someone who needs to compute a kind of combination.

Comment: Fair!  Since we're on the subject of permutations, a base R option would be `apply(expand.grid(Codes,other_Codes), MARGIN=1, FUN = \(x) { paste0("repetetivetext ", x[1], " repetetivetext ", x[2])})
`